# GIT - "importar" conteúdo de um outro repo para uma branch

Tags: git, github

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu tenho um repositório chamado "site-layout" com apenas a branch master, aonde eu desenvolvo um layout com o bootstrap v4.

Eu ainda possuo outro repositório chamado "site-old" também apenas com a branch master, aonde está o código de outro layout porém criado com o bootstrap v3.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é "importar" (não sei se seria esse o termo correto) esse "site-old" pra dentro do "site-layout" como uma nova branch que eu quero chamar de "bootstrapv3" (e depois apagar o "site-old", e depois, se possível, "espelhar" essa branch na master do "site-layout".

EDIT: Se ficar muito complicado (até é melhor), poderia ser apenas "espelhar" o conteúdo do "site old" direto na master do "site-layout", desde que isso não interfira no fork que eu já criei baseado no conteúdo da master atual.

Finalizando, pra ilustrar, a estrutura de ambos os repositórios está assim:

```
site-layout (ou site-old)
|
+--- master
```

E como eu gostaria de organizar:

```
site-layout
|
+---master ("transferir" o conteúdo daqui pra bootstrapv4, e depois passar pra cá o conteúdo da bootstrapv3 (ou site-old))
+--- bootstrapv3 (com o conteudo vindo da antiga site-old)
+--- bootstrapv4 (com o conteúdo vindo da master do site-layout)
```

Grato desde já!

Comment: Você tem alguma intensão de dar merge entre essas duas branches em algum momento?

Comment: Não.
A única coisa que eu poderia pretender fazer é colocar o conteudo de cada uma das duas branches na master (não sei realmente se dá pra fazer isso), tipo, quando eu estivesse desenvolvendo pro bootstrap v3 eu usaria ele como master, e possivelmente depois a bootstrap v4.
Se não for possível isso, tranquilo.

Comment: tenho a impressão que você não compreendeu a função da ramificação master, ela é a principal do repositório, não a "ramificação de trabalho". Pois não faz sentido transferir uma ramificação depois a outra para a master, sendo que você não vai fazer *merge*. Pelo cenário descrito é melhor que seu repositório não tenha um master, você pode configurar qual ramificação será a principal diretamente do github.

Answer (score 2):

Se a modificação entre o que tem em um repositório para o outro é completamente diferente não faz sentido manter no mesmo.

Se a atualização do bootstrap v3 para o v4 for parcial, faz sentido manter no mesmo repositório. Nesse caso acho que criar um branch e copiar e colar os arquivos e deletar os que não serão mais utilizados é a forma mais fácil.

```
//site-old
git checkout master
git checkout -b bootstrapv3
git checkout master
git checkout -b bootstrapv4
//Copie e cole todos os arquivos do repositório site-layout que são diferentes.
git add -A
git commit -am "Adição inicial de bootstrapV4"
git push origin //para criar as branches no repositório remote.
```

Agora você pode trabalhar nas duas versões independentemente.

Nesse caso você terá duas masters e a branch master não será mais utilizada ou será utiliza para replicar uma das duas versões apenas.

OBS: A branch master é apenas um padrão utilizado na geração inicial de repositórios git. Mas o git em si não tem preferência por nenhuma branch. Então ter uma branch principal que não é a master ou ter mais de uma branch principal para versões diferentes do código não é errado.

Comment: Ah puxa, e não tem como preservar os commits?
E eu pensei em passar do site-old para o site-layout, e não o contrário (os arquivos do bootstrapv4 já estão no site-layout, que é o repositório a ser mantido.

Comment: Se um nasceu dos arquvios do outro VC pode tentar adicionar um segundo remote no novo repositório. Talvez dê pra manter os commits utilizando rebase daí.

Comment: Pois é, como eu sou completamente leigo em GIT, não sei direito quais são os comandos.
Enfim, acabei desistindo dessa importação (e da pergunta) e agora estou utilizando apenas o repositorio old como repo para desenvolvimento. Não sei como funciona o sistema do stack num caso desses, mas se puder eu valido a tua resposta.

Comment: se você considerar que é uma possível resposta pra sua pergunta, mas que não resolveu seu problema pode dar um up vote. Se resolveria seu problem pode marcar como resposta =).

Answer (score 1):

Para "transferir" as ramificações basta renomear. Para importar outro repositório como ramificação, adicione o repositório remoto, faça *checkout* e exclua o remoto:

```bsh
# renomeia master (atual) para bootstrapv4
git branch -m bootstrapv4

# adicionar repositório remoto e importar como ramificação
git remote add site-old git@github.com:seu-usuario/site-old.git
git remote update site-old
git checkout -b bootstrapv3 site-old/master
git remote remove site-old
```

Conforme indiquei no comentário da pergunta, será melhor que seu projeto não tenha a ramificação master, configure a ramificação principal no github.